# Android scroll Framelayout that changes dimensions

Tags: android, scroll, android-scrollview, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout in a ScrollView like bellow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:scrollbars="vertical">
     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">
        </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In this framelayout I draw a view that changes dimensions depending on drawing parameters.

The problem is that if the drawing is out of screens bound the view that I draw does not scroll.
I'm using a framelayout because I need to draw views over views.
What can i do in this situation?

Thanks for the help.